# Association doesn't save between 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Rails 5, I have an issue when I try to save my association between these 2 models : User and Provider

**My models :**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   # Relations
   has_and_belongs_to_many :providers
end


class Provider < ApplicationRecord
  # Relations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

**the Controller :**

```
class ProvidersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @provider = current_user.providers.new
  end

  def create
    @provider = current_user.providers.new(provider_params)
    if @provider.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def provider_params
      params[:provider][:status] = 'name'
      params.require(:provider).permit(:name, :status)
    end
```

**Form :**

```
= simple_form_for @provider do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :name, required: false
  = f.button :submit
```

On the create action, a new provider is created but it is not linked to the current user. (no data is insterted in the join table)

I have no idea why I have this behavior.
In console, if i do something like :

```
@user = User.create(email: "user@test.com", password: "password")
@provider = @user.providers.create(name: "Provider1", status: "name")
@provider.save
```

then the association is correctly saved.

```
 > @user.providers
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Provider id: 17, name: "Provider1", status: "name", created_at: "2017-07-25 09:37:19", updated_at: "2017-07-25 09:37:19">]>
```

Thanks for any idea !

For info, my schema :

```
create_table "providers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "status"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "providers_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "provider_id", null: false
  t.bigint "user_id", null: false
  t.index ["provider_id", "user_id"], name: "index_providers_users_on_provider_id_and_user_id"
  t.index ["user_id", "provider_id"], name: "index_providers_users_on_user_id_and_provider_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "email", default: "", null: false
  t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
  t.string "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

Here is the log

```
  ÈStarted POST "/providers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-25 11:49:27 +0200
  Processing by ProvidersController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"27O2Tz4bbqhfRmcuq+0DIZMebSaYVc6IO/uy889Z48fF1l3c8GfIZ+WcQvZKfUeEIB5+YbrM9dON2RH47p3TIQ==", "provider"=>{"name"=>"My new provider"}, "commit"=>"Sauvegarder"}
    User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
     (0.2ms)  BEGIN
    SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "providers" ("name", "status", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "My new provider"], ["status", "name"], ["created_at", "2017-07-25 09:49:27.837165"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-25 09:49:27.837165"]]
     (4.0ms)  COMMIT
  Redirected to http://localhost:3000/providers/18/steps.location
  Completed 302 Found in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)


  Started GET "/providers/18/steps.location" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-25 11:49:27 +0200
  Processing by Providers::StepsController#index as 
    Parameters: {"provider_id"=>"18"}
  Redirected to http://localhost:3000/providers/18/steps/registration
  Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


  Started GET "/providers/18/steps/registration" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-25 11:49:27 +0200
  Processing by Providers::StepsController#show as HTML
    Parameters: {"provider_id"=>"18", "id"=>"registration"}
    Provider Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "providers".* FROM "providers" WHERE "providers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 18], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    Rendering providers/steps/registration.html.haml within layouts/provider
    User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "providers_users" ON "users"."id" = "providers_users"."user_id" WHERE "providers_users"."provider_id" = $1  [["provider_id", 18]]
    Rendered providers/steps/registration.html.haml within layouts/provider (13.2ms)
    Rendered shared/_head.html.haml (30.6ms) [cache miss]
    User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    Rendered shared/_header.html.haml (9.7ms) [cache miss]
  Completed 200 OK in 69ms (Views: 64.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Comment: Show us your logs that are generated when the submit is triggered.

Comment: @Pavan please show my log, the redirect is a bit different. Thanks !

Comment: Hold on! As per your form and the controller, you are sending inputs only for providers!

Comment: @Pavan that is to say I have to add an hidden field on the form ?

Comment: I suggest to have a look at `has_many through`. That could be your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know maybe it is not the best solution but it is the fastest that comes to my mind

```
  def create
    @provider = current_user.providers.create(provider_params)
    if @provider.id
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

This will create join table record when you use new only why that will work in case of belongs to if provider belongs to user and has user_id in migration current_user.providers.new will add user_id in the new instance, in case has and belongs to many you can do it like this, maybe there is better way but this is what came up to me first.

or something like this

```
 def create
    @provider = Provider.new(provider_params)
    if @provider.save
      current_user.providers << @provider
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

one more line but I guess looks cleaner.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: I tried this solution on my project and had result that OP expects it creates in one line provider and also join table record provider and user.

Comment: This solution works, Sedad :) In my opinion it's a little bit weird. I'm waiting a bit if there is a better solution suggested. Thank a lot !

Comment: @benoitr I edited my answer with different approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
def create
  @provider = current_user.providers.new(provider_params)
  @provider.users = [current_user]
  if @provider.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

I suggest using a `has_many through` relationship instead of `has_many_and_belongs_to`, because you can query the join table, and possibly add some more columns in the future in this join table, should the need arise.

P.S. This feels like a Rails bug / feature improvement to me. `@provider.users = [current_user]` should not be needed anymore as `@provider = current_user.providers.new(provider_params)` can already be inferred that the `@provider` object is associated already with `current_user`, and thus should be automatically assigned already. This already works with `has_many` though. Seems that only here in HABTM that it does not automatically assign.